# Check for most recent -SNAPSHOT parent

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

We have multiple developers working on a project. We have a snapshot version of the parent pom file (1.0.1-SNAPSHOT), but that is being updated pretty consistently by different developers. Is there a way for each of our child projects to ALWAYS check for the most recent SNAPSHOT version of the parent from the remote repository. We're considering https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.4/maven-settings/settings.html making the updatePolicy "always" for SNAPSHOTs for our repositories. However, this has the effective drawback of applying to everything, not just the parent project we want to be checking. If i understand *always* correctly, it will redownload everything each time. But I want that to only be the case for our parent project, not other dependencies. Is there a way to do artifact specific updatePolicies?

We have also considered using https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html but we would have to remember to add this to every child project we create.... Which seems unnecessary and frankly the wrong spot to put something that should apply to every project.

Comment: So updating means it should create new version (not SNAPSHOT's)...and that can than be handled by a CI solution in combination with versions-maven-plugin...If you have a SNAPSHOT version as your parent only this will result in non reproducible builds for the rest of the project cause this will be released sometime...?

Comment: So your impression is the parent project should consistently be a release version and then the child projects should use something like [1.0,)

Comment: I feel like that has the same problem of needing to check for new updates/versions

Comment: The parent project should be a release and the childs should update it if it should be using a version range will lead to the same problem and violate reproducible build for your child projects...I hope we are talking about a corporate parent and not about a parent of a multi module build.... I would suggest to implement a CI solution which does the update...of the parent...

Comment: I am talking about a corporate parent yes... but one that is in a pretty fluid state at the moment. Could you point me in the direction of a CI solution for something like this? It doesn't seem like Maven handles this except through the release plugin which causes more problems than it helps

Comment: See [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) ? Release plugin is not intended to update parents in that way...CI solution can built based upon to versions-maven-plugin ...

Comment: Is a viable solution to run the update-parent goal during an earlier phase of a build (e.x. validate)? Or does it need to be run as a separate build/goal executions.

Comment: The update needs to run externally cause otherwise the update will take into effect cause the pom model is not read several times..only once during "Project scanning" ..which is already done if you like to bind it to a life cycle phase...

Comment: I think my problem in that case is that theoretically before every project build we would have to run that goal separately. Which is an extra manual step before every single build.

Comment: Why manually.? Let it run every night...? Or integrate such things into a release process?